# Interface variable conversion in Golang

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have a variable which value can be string or int depend on the input. I use `interface{}` as the type. How to convert the value of that variable to `int` if the input is like `"50"`, `"45"`, or any string of int.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "strconv"

func main() {
  var limit interface{}
  limit = "50"
  page := 1
  offset := 0
  if limit != "ALL" {
        log.Println("INSIDE")
        offset = limit.(int)*page - limit.(int)
    }
    fmt.Println(offset)
}
```

Above code got:

```
interface conversion: interface {} is string, not int
```

If I use this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "strconv"

func main() {
  var limit interface{}
  limit = "50"
  page := 1
  offset := 0
  if limit != "ALL" {
        log.Println("INSIDE")
        offset = strconv.Atoi(limit)*page - strconv.Atoi(limit)
    }
  fmt.Println(offset)
}
```

I got this

```
exit status 2
 command-line-arguments
./main.go:14:24: cannot use limit (type interface {}) as type string in argument to strconv.Atoi: need type assertion
./main.go:14:24: multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context
./main.go:14:51: cannot use limit (type interface {}) as type string in argument to strconv.Atoi: need type assertion
./main.go:14:51: multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context
```

How to convert value of that variable to int?

Comment: for downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: You simply **cannot**. This is not how Go works. Please take the Tour of Go. Stop using interface{} here. Your limit is a string in the example so convert it with Atoi. You _must_ get the type right and this is done by understanding Go's type system. Learn that now. And please read and understand the error messages: They describe _exactly_ what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, in contrast to languages such as Python/JavaScript/Perl, the variables have strict types and strong boundaries. You have to write explicit code to make the conversion of a string from/to an integer. This is helpful to write safer and more performant programs.

In addition, if the variable is stored in an `interface{}` you have to use a type assertion (or a type switch) to further use the content with a specific type.

Here is your [fixed code](https://play.golang.org/p/yUYQrKyOIQq):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    var limit interface{}
    limit = "50"
    page := 1
    offset := 3
    if limit != "ALL" {
        // Type assertion
        s, isString := limit.(string)
        if !isString {
            log.Fatalf("limit is not a string but %T", limit)
        }
        // Conversion from string to int, with error handling
        l, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("%s: %v", limit, err)
        }
        offset = l*page - l
    }
    fmt.Println(offset)
}
```

However, I suggest that you just use the `string` type for the limit variable.

Answer (score 0):

### strconv package can use for this kind of conversion

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var lim interface{}
    lim = "10"
    fmt.Printf("Type is: %T\nValue is: %s \n", lim, lim.(string))
    i, _ := strconv.Atoi(lim.(string))
    fmt.Printf("After conversion value is: %d", i)
}
```

Output of the above code:

> Type is: string, Value is: 10
>   After conversion value is: 10

Comment: Good example +1. It might be slightly clearer to write https://play.golang.org/p/ckgotHV6pXh.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, value of your `limit` in fact is always string, but in one case it's value == `ALL`, otherwise it's a string representation of an integer value.

If I'm right, then I would provide following solution:

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func getOffset(limit string, page int64) (int64, error) {
    lim, err := strconv.ParseInt(limit, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        if limit == "ALL" {
            return 0, nil
        }

        return 0, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("string '%v' doesn't fit requirements, error: %v", limit, err))
    }

    offset := lim*page - lim
    return offset, nil
}
```

Full solution on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fJv9_cw18R5